# Orderer Container exited while turning on fabric network

Tags: hyperledger

2022-06-11 05:12:53.108 UTC [orderer.common.server] initializeServerConfig -> INFO 004 Starting orderer with TLS enabled
2022-06-11 05:12:53.120 UTC [blkstorage] NewProvider -> INFO 005 Creating new file ledger directory at /var/hyperledger/production/orderer/chains
2022-06-11 05:12:53.128 UTC [orderer.common.server] Main -> PANI 006 Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.example.com")
panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.example.com")

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @lepsch this problem is solved, certifications of component are expired, i re-generated and all works fine.